# 感じ and 風 to talk about how to do something

Tags: word-choice, words

I see that the nouns 感じ and 風 (also written ふう) are sometimes used to indicate how to do something. Some examples:

> こんなふうに書いてください。 
> こんな感じにカットしてください。

This is a dialogue about how to golf:

> A: アドバイス？お願いします！
> B: じゃあ、スイングするときはもっと体全体を使ってみて。こんな感じかな。
> A: えっと、こう？
> B: そうそう！
> A: はい、わかりました！

As the examples show, they often appear with こんな, そんな, あんな y どんな.

I'd like to know more about their usage, so I'd like to ask two questions:

1. Are 感じ and 風 always interchangeable? My impressions is that 感じ is more causal, but besides that I don't see any other difference.
2. How are 感じ and 風 different to the series こう, そう, ああ and どう? I mean when the latter are used to talk about the manner of an action.

Anything else you wish to share beyond these two questions is welcome because I can't find much (in English) about these usages.

Comment: 風 is more like “style”; 感じ is “feel/feeling”. i would think they  might on occasion be interchangeable but not always.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: i don’t feel i really answered much which is why i didn’t post a real answer. if i could have explained more beyond this i would have posted a true answer.

Comment: Oh, sure, I know, but I appreciate it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't feel competent enough to post an answer at first, but the comment got too long so here it is.

#### Summary

They are indeed similar in usage, however I would say that 感じ is used quite casually, as opposed to 風.

#### Details and examples

To give an example, here is a real text message from a close Japanese friend:

> 私は今日はちょっと早めに寝て、早めに起きようかなって感じ

Meaning "Today I went to bed a little early, so I think I'll get up a bit early". The 「って感じ」 part is translated only as nuance here. In spoken English, someone might say "I'll, like, get up early too", which would be comparable.

There are dozens of occasions where she used the same 「という感じ」 (or its more casual form 「って感じ」), but the only occasion where she used 「というふうに」 was when she quoted her Manager from work.

#### Final notes

I hope this gives you an idea about the difference in nuance and usage of these two similar phrases. A quick google search yielded nothing more of value, but maybe someone with deeper knowledge of Japanese, maybe a native speaker, could illuminate further.

Comment: Thank you very much!